# Is that sentence correct "we stared at her on surprised"?

Tags: sentence-structure

I have doubt about the correctness of this sentence:

> we stared at her on surprised

I would like to express. We were staring at her and  we were surprised at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"We stared at her in surprise."

This sentence implies that something about "her" is surprising, causing her viewers to be surprised.